# Jquery - Animate DIV only if the value changes on ajax reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following DIV that shows the total number of records where the Status equal's a specific value. I then check this record every few seconds to see if it changes, if it does it updates the div.

On hover over the DIV, it has a jquery animation. I wanted to see how i can animate that div when the ajax reloads and the value is different. Can you please help me out?

```
        <a href="sales-nositesurvey.php" class="box bg-danger hvr-buzz" >
           <div class="box-cell p-a-3 valign-middle">
              <i class="box-bg-icon middle right ion-android-alarm-clock"></i>
              <span class="font-size-24">
                 <strong>
                    <span class="results-salesrep-nositesurvey">
                    <?php
                       $date = new DateTime();
                       $results_of_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
                       $zeros = "00:00:00";
                       $togethernow = $results_of_date. ' ' . $zeros;
                       $mysqli_total_number_of_onsite_installs_for_the_day = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "mypassword", "orders");
                       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                           printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                           exit();
                       }
                       if ($result = $mysqli_total_number_of_onsite_installs_for_the_day->query("SELECT DISTINCT Order_Number FROM nextgenorders WHERE ShipVia='No Site Survey' AND Detail_ShipDate>='$togethernow' AND Rep_Name='".$_SESSION['full_name']."' ")) {
                       $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

                         echo $row_cnt;


                       $result->close();
                       }
                       $mysqli_total_number_of_onsite_installs_for_the_day->close();
                       ?>  
                    </span>
                    <script>
                       function refresh_div() {
                           jQuery.ajax({
                               url:'results-salesrep-nositesurvey.php',
                               type:'POST',
                               success:function(results) {
                                   jQuery(".results-salesrep-nositesurvey").html(results);

                               }
                           });
                       }

                       t = setInterval(refresh_div,5000);

                    </script>
                 </strong>
              </span>
              <br>
              <span class="font-size-15">No Site Survey</span>
           </div>
        </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the animation in the `success` callback function, you can use the available effects from jquery,  will use bounce by adding the statement

```
 $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow" );
```

Just make sure you have the `jquery.ui.css` and `jquery.ui.js` included in the page. Change your `refresh_div` function to below.

```
function refresh_div() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:'results-salesrep-nositesurvey.php' ,
    type:'POST' ,
    success:function(results) {
        jQuery ( ".results-salesrep-nositesurvey" ) . html ( results );
        $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow" );
    }
    });
}
```